# Identifier with the same name in both expression and declaration of range-based for

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, scope

Is it legal to declare a loop variable in a ranged-based for loop with the same name I use in the expression statement of the loop? I hope the example makes it clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct bar {
    std::vector<int> nums;
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.nums = {1, 2, 3};

    for(int b : b.nums)
        std::cout << b << std::endl;   
}
```

gcc 4.8 gives an error while clang 3.2 allows it.

Comment: The [bug has been reported to gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54430).

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for digging that up. Turns out I didn't find anything on bugzilla because I was searching for "ranged based for" instead of "range based for". Don't know how that term manifested in my head, same mistake happened in the title, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my reading of C++2011 6.5.4, your code of:

```
bar b;

for(int b : b.nums)
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Should be converted to:

```
bar b;

{
   auto && __range = b.nums;
   for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
       int b = *__begin;
       std::cout << b << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This to me means that **clang** is correct.

Comment: IMHO, I'd say that this is a defect in the standard. The visibility of `int b` should be from the `:` until the end of the for statement.

Comment: @rodrigo: I agreed until I thought about it some more. What would this mean: `for (auto & x : x)`?

Comment: That would be as meaningless as the simple declaration `auto &x = x;` and for the same reasons.

Comment: @rodrigo: Why? Why make that meaningless when what we have now currently works and makes sense?

Comment: @GManNickG: Why? For consistence with other parts of the language: everywhere when a name is introduced its scope starts just after the name itself. For example `void *p = &p;` is perfectly legal. The range-based-for is an exception to the rule and for no real reason other than a likely unwanted side-effect of the standard wording.

Comment: @rodrigo: I am of the opinion (and I think this is generally agreed upon) that such behavior is a mistake.  The name should not be introduced until after the initializer. Regardless, the two aren't comparable: in a range-based for loop the expression for the range is *known* to not be the initializer of the declaration (if it were, we would just have `declaration = expression`, nothing to do with the `for`). Rather, it's the declaration for each value of the range expression *within the loop*. I just don't see how they can be compared.

Answer (score 9):

**Clang is right**.

Paragraph 6.5.4/1 of the C++11 Standard defines the range-based `for` statement as follows:

> For a *range-based* for statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the expression surrounded by parentheses
>
> ```
> ( expression )
> ```
>
> and for a *range-based* for statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the braced-init-list. In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent
>   to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>           __end = end-expr;
>           __begin != __end;
>           ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

From the above, it is visible that variable `b`, which corresponds to the `for-range-declaration`, is declared inside a nested block statement, while the initializer `range-init` (which corresponds to `b.nums`) appears in the parent scope, where `b` should resolve to the object of type `bar`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: You're right, I overlooked that initially. I edited the answer, thank you

Comment: It is not so easy... from a literal interpretation of the standard, in `auto && __range = range-init;` the `range-init` is actually `b.num`, but the `int b` does not enter in the definition until 5 lines later... But again, seeing the original code, it would be expected that the `int b` hides the `bar b`.

Comment: Apologies for leading you astray. My mistake! I agree with this answer.

Comment: @sftrabbit: That's all right, your observation was OK and I should have triple-checked rather than rushing into answering ;) Lesson learnt

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this bug has now been fixed on gcc trunk. :)