# C++ async threads terminate when calling thread finishes

Tags: c++, multithreading, recursion, c++11, stdasync

I am trying to do a recursive directory listing using a multi threaded approach.  The following code works fine when replacing the async calls as a normal single threaded recursive function call but when implemented with async, the recursively started threads all seem to terminate when the initial async call made from main finishes as the output shows several calls to the function starting but the only directory where all of the files are output is the initial one and "Finished" is only output once although "Started" is output several times and some other directory's files are also output.  I suspect I am missing something fundamental.  Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code?

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <concurrent_vector.h>
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;
using namespace concurrency;

concurrent_vector<future<void>> taskList;

void searchFiles(wstring path, concurrent_queue<wstring>& fileList)
{
    wcout << L"Started " << path << endl;
    wdirectory_iterator directoryIterator(path);
    wdirectory_iterator endDirectory;
    for( ; directoryIterator != endDirectory; ++directoryIterator)
    {
        wcout << path + L"/" + (wstring)directoryIterator->path() << endl;
        if ( is_directory(directoryIterator->status() ) )
        {
            taskList.push_back( async( launch::async, searchFiles, path + 
            L"/" + (wstring)directoryIterator->path(), ref(fileList) ));
        }
        else
        {
            fileList.push( path + L"/" + (wstring)directoryIterator->path() );
        }
    }
    wcout << L"Finished " << path <<  endl;
}

int main()
{
    concurrent_queue<wstring> fileList;
    wstring path = L"..";
    taskList.push_back( async( launch::async, searchFiles, path, ref(fileList) ));
    for (auto &x: taskList)
        x.wait();
}
```

BTW some might ask why I am not using wrecursive_directory_iterator.  Apparently wrecursive_directory_iterator will throw an exception and stop with no way to continue if you do not have read permission so this method should allow you to continue on in that case.

Comment: I'd like to know why you are doing this with multiple threads at all.  That has the potential to stress the buggery out of your disk.

Comment: As you might guess this is a school project for concurrent programming so that is the point of using a multi-threaded approach.  Also the Visual Studio concurrent_vector and concurrent_queue containers are not relevant to the problem.  They are there only to implement further work on the futures and found files once I figure out this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the range-based for loop.

If we take a look at how the [range-based for statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407244/893693) is defined, we see that the end-iterator of the loop will only be calculated once. At the time of entering the loop, there is probably(this is a race) only one future in your vector(the one you pushed back in the line above). Thus after that task finishes, the iterator will be incremented and be equal to your old end-iterator and the loop will finish even though the vector might now contain more elements which got pushed back in your first task. There are even more problems to this.

The destructor of the vector which will be called after finishing the loop should normally call the destructor of all its elements which for a future from `std::async` would be equal to calling wait, though you are still adding elements to the vector while it's already in its destructor, which is probably UB.

Another point is that the end-iterator you created on entering the for-loop will be invalidated as soon as you push_back to your vector in your first thread, this means that you are operating on invalidated iterators.

As a solution I would propose to avoid the global task-list and instead use a local task-list in your `searchFiles` function, you can then wait on all your local futures in your `searchFiles` function on each level. This is a common pattern in non-managed recursive parallelism.

Note: I don't know all the details from the ppl concurrent_vector but I assume it behaves similar to a `std::vector`.

Comment: I think you're right, but I'm not sure showing the definition of the range-based `for` loop helps, and _"This means that the loop will only iterate over the first and only future in the vector."_ could be explained more clearly. **Why** does it mean that?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely OK, thanks for the feedback. I will add an update later.

Comment: Thanks alot to @bamboon for the help this solved my problem. I beat my head against the wall for hours on this one. I should have seen that it was a logic error to start waiting on the vector of futures before making sure it was finished filling. To resolve it I added an atomic counter that increments when I call the function asynchronously and decrements just before it exits. This lets me solve the second issue I had as to how to determine I was done as I didn't actually want to wait on the futures but start popping the queue and processing it.

Comment: BTW I would upvote but I don't have the reputation to do so.  I've been a long time lurker but this is my first post.